# Balancing objects of varying length in a collection of set length while maintaining order

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

I have an object each with a length associated with it. I can then have multiple of these objects and I want to put them into another collection/array with a certain set count. **Order matters** and I need every element in the top level list to have at least one object in it.

example:

object 1 called x1 with a count of 4

object 2 called x2 with a count of 3

object 3 called x3 with a count of 1

object 4 called x4 with a count of 20

put all those into an array with 3 elements (columns) and balance it much as possible.

the good outcome would be [x1] [x2,x3] [x4]

Is there an algorithm or pattern that can give me a balanced (as much as possible) collection.

Thoughts so far:

My original solution was to take the target length (totalCount/numberOfColums) of all objects, then any item over that target length would/should get its own columm. Next I would re-calculate the target length with the remaining objects and with the remaining columns and break those up.

This solution breaks down in some situations.

example:

[10] [2] [2] [3] [3] [9] [2] [10]

this breaks it out into | [10] | [2] [2] [3] |* [3] |** [9] [2] [10] |

**the last column is filled so much because as I get to the end I have to still put the items in the collection.

- The third column just has the one item of count 3, because the 9 would throw it over the target length. (I later added a tolerance to account for this, but this added many new issues when list are perfectly balance and you don't want the tolerance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: misunderstood question.

I advise a quick, greedy algorithm.  First choose your target bin size, then fill the bins greedily (as much as possible without going over).  When you're done, count the number of bins; if it's not too many you're done.  If there are too many, then increase the target and start over.  The outcome described in the comments will be achieved for a target of 11.  For a target of 10, the 9 and 2 will be split into separate bins, so that won't work.

Comment: Except I have to keep the original order that was given while trying to balance the columns. So I would need an outcome like: 


| [10] | [2] [2] [3] [3] | [9] [2] | [10] |